# Create Command line shortcuts in Windows 7

Tags: windows, command-line, alias

I'm using jsDoc to create documentations for my JavaScript files. The command I use is

```
> java -jar jsrun.jar app\run.js -a -t=templates\jsdoc mycode.js
```

What I want is to create a batch or something else (I really don't know), so that I can type

```
> jsdoc mycode.js
```

Without having to specify any folders or change my working directory in the command line.

Is this possible? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a batch file called "jsdoc.bat" and ensure that you have a path you your jsdoc folder / app folder (or code the full locations in). Ensure there is a path to wherever you put this file

```
set path = c:\whereverthebatfileis\
```

The following would be the code.

```
java -jar jsrun.jar  c:\whateverfolder\app\run.js -a -t=c:\whateverfolder\templates\jsdoc\ %1
```

Usage would be:

jsdoc myfile.js

Comment: can you specify where shall I put "set path = c:\doc_js"??

Comment: Either type it in the command line, or set a path in your enviornment variables (right click your computer and go to properties, click advanced system settings, it will be at the bottom). Find "PATH" in your system variables and add the location to the list. It should be permanant either way.